# What is the distinction between a payment and transaction in the Xero API?

Tags: xero-api

What is the distinction between a payment and transaction in the Xero API? Does a payment create a transaction? Or are transactions only created when they are manually added? Are all organic transactions coming in as payments, rather than transactions?

Comment: By "transactions", do you mean bank transactions? If so, I think the main difference is that a payment is put against an invoice or credit note, but I don't think that's the case for a bank transaction. On my client's system, for example, I use a bank transaction "receive-prepayment" to record when a customer pays a cash deposit against future work because there's no invoice at that point.

Comment: @droopsnoot Yeah I do mean bank transactions. OK, so a payment is completely separate from a bank transaction? It doesn't create a linked transaction?

Comment: A payment appears in the bank account on Xero, as do my receive-prepayment bank transactions.  But a payment is specifically against an invoice / credit note.

Answer (score 0):

A Journal entry is created for every type of transaction in Xero. So for the most comprehensive endpoint of the API I'd start there. However the greater level of detail will exist in the supplementary endpoints like invoices, bills, spent money, receive money.
There are other threads on here talking about the difference between "Bank Transactions" and the other API endpoints, as this actually excludes transactions that show in Xero but are not accessible through this specific endpoint.